# Show software keyboard after tap button

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I need to show the software keyboard after the user clicks on a button. Now I am hiding the keyboard and showing it after user clicks on button, but when the user clicks on an Edit-text, the keyboard shows itself. 
I has two button, when user clicks at first button he see softwear keyboard, when he click at second button the softwere keyboard is hiding and he see control fragment, which controls edittext. And when user sees the control fragment and tap for edittext the softwear keyboard is displayed. I need that to not show this softwear keyboard. Softwear keyboard should be shown only when the user taps on the first button

How can I stop the soft keyboard showing, but have it still working when clicked on the button?

Answer (score 0):

set `editText.setFocusable(false);`  initiall and on button click use `editText.setFocusable(true);` and 
        `editText.requestFocus();`

Comment: No, I think you don't understand me. I has two button, when user clicks at first button he see softwear keyboard, when he click at second button the softwere keyboard is hiding and he see control fragment, which controls edittext. And when user sees the control fragment and tap  for edittext the softwear keyboard is displayed. I need that  to not show this softwear keyboard. Softwear keyboard should be shown only when the user taps on the first button.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

To force the soft keyboard to appear, you can use

```
EditText yourEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

And for removing the focus on EditText, saddly you need to have a dummy View to grab focus.

I hope this helps
To close it you can use

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(yourEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: No, I think you don't understand me. I has two button, when user clicks at first button he see softwear keyboard, when he click at second button the softwere keyboard is hiding and he see control fragment, which controls edittext. And when user sees the control fragment and tap  for edittext the softwear keyboard is displayed. I need that  to not show this softwear keyboard. Softwear keyboard should be shown only when the user taps on the first button.